# Django - Como redirecionar o usuário para as outras paginas da aplicação?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

No menu da template eu tenho um menu `Dropdown` com os link's para as outras paginas 
do aplicativo!

No menu da pagina home da aplicação tenho os link's para as outras paginas da aplicação! 
Ex: Home, Relatorios, Sobre... Todos são link's que ao clicar deveriam direcionar para as respectivas paginas.

Para tratar esse redirecionamento eu adicionei nas tag's `<a>` do meu template base uma função onclik que redireciona para as devidas paginas.

O codigo do menu dropdown ficou assim:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8000/cadLivro';">Cadastrar Livros</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8000/cadUsuario';">Cadastrar Usuários</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8000/cadFuncionario';">Cadastrar Funcionários</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header">Pesquisa</li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8000/pesqLivro';">Livro</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8000/pesqUsuario';">Usuário</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8000/pesqFuncionario';">Funcionário</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Foi o que eu consegui fazer, pois não tenho muito conhecimento de javascript(muito menos jQuery), o que eu fiz é uma "gambiarra" e só funcionaria se eu fosse rodar a aplicação localmente e na porta 8000. Como eu faço esse redirecionamento de uma maneira correta ?!

Comment: Como está seu código JavaScript e seu `urls.py`? Está difícil entender qual é sua dúvida somente com o que está sendo perguntado, adicione mais detalhes à sua pergunta por favor.

Comment: No menu da pagina home da aplicação tenho os link's para as outras paginas da aplicação! 

Ex: Home, Relatorios, Sobre...
Todos são link's que ao clicar deveriam direcionar para as respectivas paginas. 

Acontece que como não fiz referencia a estes links no html e nem tenho funções JS para tratar. Eu gostaria de saber se no Django eu posso tratar esse evento de click nos links para que ao clicar ele me direcione para as paginas!

Comment: Basicamente, você pode colocar *o que você quiser* no HTML/JavaScript, que pro Django só o que importa é que a URL final tenha uma entrada correspondente no `urls.py`. Se isso é feito através de um link direto, de Ajax, via `location.href`, `new Window`, não importa... Da mesma forma, o que sua função `onclick` faz não diz respeito ao Django, é tudo no lado cliente mesmo. Se você está tendo problemas, *provavelmente* é uma simples URL mal construída, mostre o código (o trecho relevante do template) que talvez possamos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Ex.: Vi no seu link no Github que cada link possui um `href` to tipo `#cadLivros`, `#cadUsuarios` etc. Você poderia a princípio colocar um código JavaScript que transformasse esses fragmentos em URLs completas. Mas isso é tudo no lado cliente, não tem nada *no Django* que possa te ajudar com isso.

Comment: pergunta reformulada

Comment: Agora, sim, estou entendendo qual é sua dúvida! Votei pela reabertura, quando isso acontecer posto uma resposta. Por ora, deixo [esse link no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4599423/520779) mostrando como fazer.

Comment: Ainda não entendi o que você está querendo fazer, onclick dentro de uma tag `<a>`? Por que não colocar o endereço direto no atributo `href`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em princípio, você poderia usar caminhos absolutos (ou mesmo relativos) em vez de URLs completas. Dessa forma, o link levaria para um caminho dentro do seu domínio, seja ele qual for:

```
/cadLivro/
cadLivro/
```

Se você estiver em `http://localhost:8000/`, esses caminhos levariam a:

```
http://localhost:8000/cadLivro/
http://localhost:8000/cadLivro/
```

Se você estiver em `http://example.com/projeto/django/`, esses caminhos levariam a:

```
http://example.com/cadLivro/
http://example.com/projeto/django/cadLivro/
```

Entretanto, uma solução melhor é usar a *template tag* [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#url) para montar automaticamente o caminho a partir da view desejada. Além de respeitar o princípio [DRY](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (por não ficar repetindo URLs em várias partes do sistema), ela garante que o link enviará sempre para a URL correta, mesmo se no futuro você mudar o arquivo `urls.py` para servir suas views em um caminho diferente. Então, se seu `urls.py` estiver assim (só um exemplo, não faça assim na prática pois é super inconsistente):

```
(r'^cadLivro/', view_cadastro_livros, name='cadLivro'),
(r'^cadastro/usuario/', usuarios.views.cadastro_usuarios, name='cadUsuario'),
(r'^funcionario/', include('funcionarios.urls')), # Aqui dentro tem uma view cadFuncionario
```

No seu template basta você fazer:

```
{% url 'cadLivro' %}
{% url 'cadUsuario' %}
{% url 'cadFuncionario' %}
```

Que o Django vai substituir pela URL completa e correta.

Isso pode ser feito em qualquer lugar do template (esteja ele gerando um HTML ou outra coisa, esteja a tag dentro de um atributo ou fora). Por exemplo, a maneira mais simples de fazer o que você quer (que o link leve a uma outra página) é simplesmente usar a própria URL como `href` (como [sugerido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16086/django-como-redirecionar-o-usuario-para-as-outras-paginas-da-aplicacao#comment32703_16086) por Orion nos comentários):

```
<li><a href="{% url 'cadLivro' %}">Cadastrar Livros</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'cadUsuario' %}">Cadastrar Usuários</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'cadFuncionario' %}">Cadastrar Funcionários</a></li>
```

Mas você *poderia* também fazer isso de outras formas:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="window.location='{% url 'cadLivro' %}';">Cadastrar Livros</a></li>

<li><a href="#" onclick="new Window('{% url 'cadLivro' %}', '_blank');">Cadastrar Livros</a></li>

<li><a href="#" onclick="irPara('{% url 'cadLivro' %}');">Cadastrar Livros</a></li>

<li><a href="#" data-url="{% url 'cadLivro' %}">Cadastrar Livros</a></li>
<!-- Usando jQuery por exemplo para fazer algo com o data-url -->
```

Etc. Mas se não tiver nenhum motivo especial para "complicar", use a forma mais simples mesmo (o ideal, já que você não está usando JavaScript extensivamente no seu projeto).

Answer (score 0):

se no seu arquivo urls, voce estiver usando o import path ao invés do url, será necessario voce configurar o arquivo urls.py no diretorio da sua aplicacao:

Exemplo tenho na pasta templates os \arquivos home.html e contato.html

## ---projeto_base/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from core import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('contato/', views.contato, name='contato'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

## ---Tenho uma aplicacao chamada core, onde estao os templates citados

## ---dentro deste diretorio no arquivo urls.py

## from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('', views.contato, name='contato'),
]

--è importante resaltar a importancia dos 'names', eles serao referenciados no link